# Parsing JSON in a singleton

Tags: ios, json, swift

Currently I'm trying to determine the best way to parse JSON in a singleton so that multiple classes can have to it. That way there is no stored data in the singleton and it stays decoupled. I've come up with a JSON parsing function but am wondering is there a better way to do it. Here is the function I'm currently using:

```
  func parseJSONData(_ jsonData: Data?) -> [String : AnyObject]?
  {
    if let data = jsonData {

      do {
        let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject]//Parses data into a dictionary

          // print(jsonDictionary)

        return jsonDictionary

      } catch let error as NSError {
          print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }
       return nil
  }
```

Comment: You can start by using the correct dictionary type change `[String: AnyObject]` to `[String : Any]`. Btw using `options: .mutableContainers`is pointless. Just omit let options parameter, make your method throw and change your return type to non optional. `return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]`

Comment: I would suggest instead of just converting your JSON data into a dictionary, to structure your data and make it Codable and decode it before storing it in your Singleton property

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below. This is just simple example of Singleton for get data from URL.

```
final class Network {

static let sharedInstance = Network()

private init(){}


var arrayJson = [[String : String]]()




func get(completition: @escaping (_ json: [[String : String]]) -> Void){
    let Url = "Your String URL"
    guard let loanUrl = URL(string: Url) else { return }

    let request = URLRequest(url: loanUrl)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {( data, response, error) -> Void in

       if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }   

        // Parse JSON data

        if let data = data {
            print(data)
                do {
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]

                let jsons = jsonResult?["root"] as! [[String : String]]
                self.arrayJson = jsons
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completition(jsons)
                }


            } catch {print(error)}
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

To call Singleton, you will write in your ViewController.swift:

```
Network.sharedInstance.get{ (tmp) in
        print("ok")
    }
```

When you will see printed in console "ok", it means that the arrayJson is populated, and you can check like this:

```
print(Network.sharedInstance.arraJson.count)
```

You can see how many element are present in array.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing, you don’t need a singleton. That is a valid approach, but there are other ways to provide functions that everything in your app will get access to:

1) Make a protocol and put the functions in a protocol extension. That way, adopting types get these functions for free.

2) Make it a global function. You can simply declare a func outside of any class or struct, and then your whole app can just call it without a prefix.

3) Make it a static or class function. Then you don’t need to initialize anything to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual point into doing the parsing right in the network management singleton. Of course, the right approach to the problem is to build up a NetworkManager for every connection you have to do in your app, but personally I would suggest to implement the parsing methods in the class that build up your model. Your approach isn't wrong, don't misunderstand me, but it's way cleaner if you put the parser method in the class definition, so every class will have its own particular parser.

Also, notice that the `return nil` statement is at the end of the parseJSONData function, thus you will always that function return nil. To have that method work in the right way, you have to put the `return nil` statement in the catch block or, as I always do, declare a local variable in the function of the same type that you want to return and, in case the parsing is right, fill it. Hope it helped.